# Nested slice is not updating

Tags: go

I'm about 1 month into learning Go and I've read quite a bit about `range` and `slices` and all of the perils that come along with this complex topic.  Unfortunately, I'm sort of stumped on this particular issue.  I'm hoping this example isn't too contrived, but I tried to come up with a minimal example.

The issue is that the first time I add `bird` via `addNoise`, the `bird` gets added, but it doesn't make a sound.  If I call `addNoise` a second time with `bird`, then it seems to work OK.  However, I'm still missing the first sound I tried to add.

I think the problem lies solely in how I'm returning the `animal` in `getOrCreateAnimal`, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.  I suspect that the return address of the **newly created** `animal` is different than the one that is stored in the slice.

I probably overlooked an important fact about slices and I truly appreciate somebody helping me understand what I'm missing.

I'm running this example on Go 1.15.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Barn struct {
    animals []Animal
}

type Animal struct {
    name   string
    noises []string
}

type BarnService struct {
    barn Barn
}

func (fs *BarnService) indexOfAnimal(name string) int {
    for idx := range fs.barn.animals {
        if fs.barn.animals[idx].name == name {
            return idx
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func (fs *BarnService) getAnimal(name string) *Animal {
    idx := fs.indexOfAnimal(name)
    if idx == -1 {
        return nil
    }
    return &fs.barn.animals[idx]
}

func (fs *BarnService) getOrCreateAnimal(name string) (animal *Animal) {
    animal = fs.getAnimal(name)
    if animal == nil {
        animal = &Animal{name: name, noises: []string{}}
        fs.barn.animals = append(fs.barn.animals, *animal)
    }
    return
}

func (fs *BarnService) addNoise(noise string, barValue string) {
    animal := fs.getOrCreateAnimal(barValue)
    animal.noises = append(animal.noises, noise)
}

var fs = BarnService{
    barn: Barn{animals: []Animal{{name: "cat"}, {name: "cow"}}},
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("1-barn = %+v\n", fs.barn)
    fs.addNoise("meow", "cat")
    fs.addNoise("purr", "cat")
    fs.addNoise("hiss", "cat")
    fs.addNoise("moo", "cow")
    fs.addNoise("moo", "cow")
    fs.addNoise("peep", "bird")  //Bird gets created but doesn't make a peep
    fmt.Printf("2-barn = %+v\n", fs.barn)
    fs.addNoise("peep", "bird")  //OK now bird peeps, but it should say "peep peep"
    fmt.Printf("3-barn = %+v\n", fs.barn)
}
```

Output:

```
1-barn = {animals:[{name:cat noises:[]} {name:cow noises:[]}]}
2-barn = {animals:[{name:cat noises:[meow purr hiss]} {name:cow noises:[moo moo]} {name:bird noises:[]}]}
3-barn = {animals:[{name:cat noises:[meow purr hiss]} {name:cow noises:[moo moo]} {name:bird noises:[peep]}]}
```

Comment: Change `animals []Animal` to `animals []*Animal`, fix subsequent compiler errors and you should be good to go. https://play.golang.org/p/uH8z553HXmL (i've added stringer implementations so you can see the results in the output).

Comment: Your main problem is this `fs.barn.animals = append(fs.barn.animals, *animal)`, here you're storing a **copy** of `animal` and then the `*Animal` pointer that's returned by the enclosing function points to the original value allocated before the append, so any modification to that will not be reflected in the copy that's sitting in the slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Animal` instance you're returning and the one you're adding to your slice aren't the same. Try returning a pointer to the instance in the slice and you should be fine

```
func (fs *BarnService) getOrCreateAnimal(name string) (animal *Animal) {
    animal = fs.getAnimal(name)
    if animal == nil {
        ani := Animal{name: name, noises: []string{}}
        fs.barn.animals = append(fs.barn.animals, ani)

        animal = &fs.barn.animals[len(fs.barn.animals)-1]
    }
    return
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Wzt0X0yQ_55)

Comment: @TimReddy https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers